# Python scrapy, re compiling efficiency paradox in loop

Tags: python, regex, loops, compilation, scrapy

I am totally new to programming but I come across with this bizarre phenomenon that I could not answer. Please point me in the right direction. I started crawling a entirely javascript built webpage with ajax tables. First I started with selenium and it worked well. However, I noticed that someone of you pros here mentioned scrapy is much faster. Then I tried and succeeded in building the crawler under scrapy, with a hell of headache.

I need to use re to extract the javascript strings and what happened next confused me. Here is what the python doc says(https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

*"but using re.compile() and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program."*

I first started with using re.search(pattern,str) **in a loop**. Scrapy crawled 202 pages in **3 seconds** (finish time - start time).

Then I followed the Python doc's suggestion, compiling re.compile(pattern) **before the loop** to improve efficiency. Scrapy crawled the same 202 pages with **37 seconds**. What is going on here?

Here is the some of the code, other suggestions to improve the code is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT2: I was too presumptuous to base my view on a single run. 
Later 3 tests with 2000 webpages show that regex compiling within the loop is finished in 25s on average. With the same 2000 webpages regex compiling before the loop is finished in 24s on average.**

**EDIT:**
Here is the webpage I am trying to crawl
http://trac.syr.edu/phptools/immigration/detainhistory/
I am trying to crawl basically everything on a year-month basis from this database. There are three javascript generated columns on this webpage. When you select options form these drop-down menus, the webpage send back sql queries to its server and generate corresponding contents. I figured out directly generating these pre-defined queries to crawl all the table contents, however, it is great pain.

```
 def parseYM(self, response):
        c_list =response.xpath()
        c_list_num = len(c_list)
        item2 = response.meta['item']
        # compiling before loop
        # search_c=re.comple(pattern1)
        # search_cid=re.comple(pattern2)
        for j in range(c_list):
            item = myItem()
            item[1] = item2[1]
            item['id'] = item2['id']
            ym_id = item['ymid']
            item[3] = re.search(pattern1, c_list[j]).group(1)
            tmp1 = re.search(pattern2, c_list[j]).group(1)
            # item['3'] = search_c.search(c_list[j]).group(1)
            # tmp1 = search_cid.search(c_list[j]).group(1)
            item[4] = tmp1
            link1 = 'link1'
            request = Request(link1, self.parse2, meta={'item': item}, dont_filter=True)
            yield request
```

Unnecessary temp variable is used to avoid long lines. Maybe there are better ways? I have a feeling that the regular expression issue has something to do with the twisted reactor. The twisted doc is quite intimidating to newbies like me...

Comment: BTW: javascript mostly read data from server as JSON string which you can convert to python dictionary using `json` module.

Comment: Thanks. I tried js2xml and no good. I will try and see if json could save me some trouble.

Comment: if you show real url then we can see page and it is easier to say something more.

Comment: Put url in question and describe what exactly you try to get from page.

Comment: what "java columns" ? what "different web request" ? what "webpages" ? You have to describe it more precisely. And do it in question - it will be more readalbe for all people - maybe someone else will be able to help

Comment: Thanks. Done. I hope I made it clear now.

Comment: I see tables. Page gets it from server as `<table>` with some extra data at start. But table is very regular - it starts in row 23 so you could use standard string functions to cut it off and then you can parse it (with modul `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup`). Or you still use standard string functions (ie. `split('<td>')`, slicing - items start in column 78) to get every item without regex. Standard string functions should be faster then regex.

Comment: I tried to use string functions as much as possible. However, I need to extract the identifiers to generate request urls like this one: <a href="javascript:m.tableClick('fymon', '70');">2010-08</a>. I am not sure how to get this '70' id without using regex. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: if there is always `fymon` then you can use slicing like `'''<a href="javascript:m.tableClick('fymon', '70');">2010-08</a>'''[43:-16]`

Comment: if there can be different word then you can use `split` because there is alway `, '` before `70` and `');` after `70` - `'''<a href="javascript:m.tableClick('fymon', '70');">2010-08</a>'''.split(" '", 1)[1].split("'", 1)[0]`

Comment: You should not be measuring performance at a crude level when dealing with network I/O. The performance of scraping is dependent on a lot of factors, such as your network speed, whether the site implements rate limiting, etc. If you observed this behavior over multiple runs, please say so in your post. Concluding about the performance of an inbuilt module based on a single run that is heavily dependent on network I/O is inadvisable.

Comment: @Havan Agrawal You are so right! I was too presumptuous to say these words. I did some test again and couldn't tell the time difference. I will edit my post.